# Erro em Dll Visual Studio Installer

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, dll, instalador

Estou com o seguinte problema: quando vou dar o build no projeto do visual studio installer para gerar o instalador, me retorna o erro:

[image]

Eu consigo ver as dependências de todas as demais dll's e quando clico para ver as dessa dll, ele me retorna:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu costumava reconstruir esses projetos de instalação a partir do zero quando eles pararam de funcionar (por qualquer motivo), mas eu encontrei uma solução muito mais rápida (e menos propensa a erros). Funciona para mim,talvez funcione para você também.

1- Remova o projeto do instalador da sua solução através da interface IDE

2-Adicione o projeto do instalador de volta à sua solução (Adicionar> Projeto existente ...)

3-Rebuild

Comment: Não deu certo :/

Comment: @GabrielSouza dê uma olhada nesse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233146/unable-to-update-dependencies-of-the-project-after-committing-to-subversion).

Comment: Caso não funcione,tente reiniciar o seu Visual Studio.

Comment: também não foi :/